# Automatically Mark As Read in MS Outlook 2013 when moving to specific Folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, gmail, microsoft-outlook-2013, rules

I've recently created  'unified inbox' and 'unified sent items' folders in MS Outlook 2013.  I set up 2 rules to move all my sent items (for Gmail and for AOL, respectively)  to my 'unified sent items' folder. However, I don't get a 'mark as sent' action as an option when I am setting up the Rules. This means that all of the sent mails that are transferred to my 'unified sent items' folder appear in Bold text as 'Unread' status.   Does anybody know:

1. why I'm not seeing the 'mark as read' option in the actions list?
2. assuming this omission is unavoidable for some reason, is there some workaround to mark the items as 'read' status as they are transferred?

[see actions list that I see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRQVU.png)

Answer (score -1):

'mark it as read' action exists in the Outlook Inbox rule, check it again.

[image]

Comment: I don't see the same list as you.  See link I added above to my question which shows what I see.  The list is context sensitive for some reason.  Does anyone know why I don't see the 'mark as read option' or how I can get around it.

Comment: What's your Outlook build number?

Comment: It is 15.0.5153.1001

Comment: I understand you install Outlook 2013 client on your PC, Please try Outlook 2016/2019, then check the result.

Comment: I have Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013 installed and it is fully up to date.  There is no update option to Office 2016.  I do not want buy that product, I want get this working on 2013, or establish some kind of workaround.

Comment: Incoming and Outgoing rules are kinda different.